# “adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> true “ does't work

Tags: android, adb

I want to test App standby mode. The devices I use is Galaxy S7 edge and virtual device with an Android 6.0 (API level 23).

I use:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
$ adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> true
```

When I test if the app is actually in standby using `adb shell am get-inactive <packageName>` I always obtain the following result `Idle=false`. Did anyone else experience the same behavior?

Answer (score 2):

it's too late, but i had same problem.

i was figure it out, just remove `<>`.

it means -> `adb shell am set-inactive packageName true`

like

```
adb shell am set-inactive com.abc.abcd true
```

not

```
adb shell am set-inactive <com.abc.abcd> true
```

Comment: terminal say nothing after insert this command

Answer (score -3):

You probably aren't using the right package name. Check if you are using the right one with this in your main activity.

```
Log.d("PACKAGE NAME", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Comment: Yes mine package name is same and still i fund "The system cannot find the file specified."